# Correct path when you can move only like chess horse

Tags: python, algorithm, logic

I found an interesting problem.
So we have a dialpad (see picture). The input is a number which can be dialed on the dialpad. The thing is, that the first number can be any number on the dialpad, but after that we can only move like a chess horse. For example if we dialed 2943 than it would be correct. If the input was 3819, than it would be incorrect, because from 1 we cannot access 9 via chess horse move. Can anybody help me?

[image: A flip-phone style 3x3 dialpad. The numbers are ordered 1-9 from top left to bottom right in standard reading order.]

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting on SO

Comment: Also, what about 555555?

Comment: Can 6 and 4 move to 0?

Comment: Start with listing out each valid move for each digit, e.g. 1 => (6, 8), 2 => (7, 9)...  Add to post - and it will also likely give you ideas on solution.

Comment: You could construct a [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) to recognize this language. (By construction: previous button press is a state, transitions exist between knights-moves, eg state 1 has transitions to state 6 & 7, and if it receives any other input it moves to a rejecting state.)

By DFA/regular-expression equivalence, you could make a regex to recognize this language, though I think it'd be rather long(?)

Comment: and what is your problem? What did you try to resolve it? Where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

I think i have solved it, thank you for help.

```
possible_moves = {
1:('6', '8'),
2:('7', '9'),
3:('4', '8'),
4:('3', '9'),
6:('1', '7'),
7:('2', '6'),
8:('1', '3'),
9:('2', '4'),
}

def solve(number):
    for i in range(len(number)-1):
        if number[i+1] not in possible_moves[int(number[i])]:
            return "NO"
    return "YES"


number = input()
print(solve(number))
```

Comment: How can you move to 8 from 6 or from 9 to 7 like a chess horse?

Comment: @soumya-kole i cannot, the keys in dict point to values which are accessible, so when i type nuber one i can land only on 6 or 7.